# How to stop phone's default font size from influencing font size inside the Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, fonts, font-size, typography

So I made a Flutter app. I defined all the font sizes to be dynamic (render properly as per the screen sizes).

Everything was working great until I opened the application on a phone which was using a larger font size (changed from within the device settings). Even though, I'd programmed my text size to render itself dynamically, it fails if the user is not using the phone's default font size and has kept it at a larger size.

Now, the question is, How do I stop the phone's font size (chosen within Text Size in Settings) to influence anything that is inside my app? I want to render the same text size that I've defined inside my flutter app, no matter what the settings are.

Is there a way to do it ? Or if there's no way to stop this influencing part, what other solutions do I have here ?

Comment: Did you use textScaleFactor in your code?

Comment: Nope. I didn't.

Comment: @Wiktor Tried now but Its doing absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can override the the text scale factor provided by the system like this:

```
 MaterialApp(
      builder:  (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0, ), //set desired text scale factor here
          child: child,
        );
      },
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
```

if you find this answer as help please mark this answer as accepted